# Oracle aggregate function to determine what percentage of various columns are not null

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions

Consider the following table:

```
id | name | phone | email
------------------------_-----
1  |  bob | null  | me@me.com
2  |  bob | null  | null
3  |  bob | 12345 | null
4  |  bob | 23456 | null
```

I'd like a single query that can aggregate counts of how many fields are not null, among phone and email. So the results would be:

```
phone | email
-------------
   2  |  1
```

I need to find out values like this for each of 175 columns of a table with over a million rows.

The query does not need to be beautiful, and it doesn't need to be particularly fast. But I'd prefer if it could be in one (possibly nested) query, rather than a script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about

```
SELECT count(*) as record_count,
       count(phone) as phone_not_null,
       count(email) as email_not_null
  FROM yourtable
```

`count(columnname)` counts how many times the value is not null, and `count(*)` counts  the number of records.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know you could do that ... always have done `count(*) where phone is not null`

Answer (score 1):

For percentage, count non-null values and total values, then do the math:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(phone) / COUNT(*) * 100 AS PctNonNullPhone,
  COUNT(email) / COUNT(*) * 100 AS PctNonNullEmail
FROM MyTable
```

`COUNT(phone)` will only count a row if `phone` is not null. `COUNT(*)` counts every row, without conditions.

---

**Addendum**: David Aldridge pointed out that an empty table will be a problem. He's right: it will cause a divide by zero error. The `NULLIF` function is handy for getting around this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(phone) / NULLIF(COUNT(*), 0) * 100 AS PctNonNullPhone,
  COUNT(email) / NULLIF(COUNT(*), 0) * 100 AS PctNonNullEmail
FROM MyTable
```

In this version, if the table is empty (meaning `COUNT(*)` equals zero), the two columns will be null.

Comment: Look out for empty tables though

Comment: Good point - I thought about that but wanted to keep the query simple. I'll update with a safer alternative.